# How do configure Zend_Form to use array notation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form-sub-form

I'm having difficulty configuring Zend_Form. I have a Zend_Form sub-class. The form has some required information and some additional information. I want the additional information to be accessible via an array. The submitted data will look something like this:

```
$formData['required1']
$formData['required2']
$formData['addiotnalData']['aData1']
$formData['addiotnalData']['aData2']
```

I've Googled this and tried all the suggestions I've found (using subForms and setting the  `Zend_Form::setIsArray($flag)` and `Zend_Form::setElementsBelongTo($array)` methods), but have not figured out how to do this.

What am I doing wrong? How do I set the names of form elements so that I can access the data with array notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it! The problem is a custom decorator that was being used.

```
//In
$subForm = new Form_SubForm(); //this can be a Zend_Form or Zend_Form_SubForm     
$subForm->setIsArray(true);
$this->addSubForm($subForm, 'subform');
```

Elements will be rendered with a id of `subform-elementname` and a name of `subform[elementname]`.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and made the changes you have told. But this is not working according to my exceptions. what about custom decorators???

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer because $form->setIsArray(TRUE) was not working with my custom decorator for elements. My custom ViewScript decorator was needed for rendering the Zend_Form_Element. 
The problem, it was rendering the element name with $this->element->getName(). I had to use $this->element->getFullyQualifiedName() in the ViewScript decorator script.