# create a input field with multi keyed array in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

I want to create a form similar to the form given below using Zend framework

```
<input type="text" name="number[]" />
```

I tried with the following code

```
$element1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('element', array('isArray' => true));
        $element1->setName('element');
        $element2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('element', array('isArray' => true));
        $element2->setName('element');
```

But i came across a problem as i could only get the latest value of the array. I want to get full array in the textfield name 'number'.

Could you please help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using array notations for form elements names in Zend_Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164453/using-array-notations-for-form-elements-names-in-zend-form)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Zend Form to use Array Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928551/how-do-configure-zend-form-to-use-array-notation)

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do that unless the name of the input change for something like: number[first] or number[0]. Only multicheckbox allow empty indexes. Am I right @Gordon ?

Comment: @Keyne afaik that is correct. [The ZForm architecture does not allow for empty element names](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3782). [There seems a user-supplied patch for this, which I've neder used and cannot tell anything about it](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9516)